# Use [e.target.name]=e.target.value inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object:

```
 const itemDataObject = {
    sort: '',
    title_item_lateral: '',
    text_item_lateral: '',
    image_lateral: [
      {
        title_image_lateral: '',
        path_image_lateral: '',
      },
    ],
    document_lateral: '',
    links: [
      {
        title_link: '',
        link: '',
      },
    ],
  };
```

and i need to fill it in a form.

i use this function:

```
const handleChange = (i, e) => { 
    let itemData = [...item_lateral];
    itemData[i][e.target.name]=e.target.value;    
    setItems(itemData);        
    setNewLateral({...lateral, item_lateral, title_lateral});
    handleChangeChat(e);   };
```

and this inside the form:

```
        <div>
                {item_lateral.map((input, i) => ( 
                  <>  
                    { !(input.button_pressed === 'image' || input.button_pressed === 
       'links') && 
                   <div className="row align-item_lateral-center" key= 
        {input.button_pressed + i + 1}> 
                     <div className="col-2 mt-3">
                       <h3>{input.button_pressed}</h3>  
                     </div>
                     <div className="col-10">                 
                       <input
                         placeholder={input.button_pressed}
                         id={i}
                         className='form-control mt-3'                    
                         name={input.button_pressed}    
                         onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                         type="text"                         
                       />
                     </div>
                   </div>
                    }                               
                    {  input.button_pressed  === 'image' && 
                <>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key= 
                {input.button_pressed + i + 2}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Imagen: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-10'>
                      <input
                        placeholder='title_image_lateral'
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='title_image_lateral'   
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                             
                      /> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key= 
            {input.button_pressed + i + 1}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Image Path: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-10'>
                      <input
                        placeholder='path_image_lateral'
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='path_image_lateral'    
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                               
                      /> 
                    </div>
                  </div>                  
                </>
                    }                     
                    {input.button_pressed === 'links' &&
                <>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key= 
         {input.button_pressed + i+2}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Title Link: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8">
                      <input
                        placeholder='titel_link' 
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='titel_link'    
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                              
                      /> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key={i}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Link: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8">
                      <input
                        placeholder='link'
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='link'    
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                              
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
                    }  
                  </>                          
                ))}
            
              </div>
```

The form works onsubmit, and create values in the object with the property name, and the value.

But if the property (p.e: 'title_image_lateral'), not put the new value in the correct place in the object, instead create a new element in the root of the object: title_image_lateral: (value submited in the form).

I thik that i can change the 'root' for the **itemData[i][e.target.name]=e.target.value;** , but i can not achieve.

Maybe i can create state for this values, and then onsubmit the form, set in the object...but maybe is made a big surround.

Some light for my issue.

Thanks.

Here the entire file:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";


const LateralWindow = ({token}) => { 
  
  const itemDataObject = {
    sort: '',
    title_item_lateral: '',
    text_item_lateral: '',
    image_lateral: [
      {
        title_image_lateral: '',
        path_image_lateral: '',
      },
    ],
    document_lateral: '',
    links: [
      {
        title_link: '',
        link: '',
      },
    ],
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const generalInfo = useSelector(state=> state.faqsGralInfo); 
  const {
    description,
    typeResponse,
    rolViews,
    workLoadLevel,
    id,
    id_intent,
    corpusArea,
    corpusName,    
  } = generalInfo;

 
 
  const [ finalResponse, setFinalResponse ] = useState({});    
  const [ newJsonResponse, setNewJsonResponse ] = useState( {});
  const [ title_lateral, setTitleLateral ] = useState('');
  const [ item_lateral, setItems ] = useState([]);
  const [ lateral, setNewLateral] = useState({
    title_lateral: title_lateral,
    item_lateral: [item_lateral]
  });
  
  let buttonPressed;

  const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(['inicial']);
  console.log(nameValue);
 
  const addFields = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonPressed = e.target.value;
    setNameValue(buttonPressed);    
    let newItemField;
    newItemField = { ...itemDataObject, button_pressed: buttonPressed };
    setItems([...item_lateral, newItemField]);   
  };


  const handleChangeChat = (e) => {    
    setFinalResponse({...finalResponse, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});    
    setNewJsonResponse({
      ...newJsonResponse,
      accesToken: token,      
      newDataResponse: {
        description, 
        typeResponse,
        rolViews, 
        workLoadLevel, 
        id, 
        id_intent, 
        response_json_new:{finalResponse, lateral}, 
        corpusArea, 
        corpusName,
        lateral_W: generalInfo.lateral_W === 'true' ? 1 : 0 ,        
      }
    },
    );
  };
  
  const handleChange = (i, e) => { 
    let itemData = [...item_lateral];
    itemData[i][e.target.name]=e.target.value;    
    setItems(itemData);        
    setNewLateral({...lateral, item_lateral, title_lateral});
    handleChangeChat(e);   };
   
  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();        
  };
  const sendToCorpus = () => {    
    /* setTimeout(() => {
      window.location = '/corpus';
    }, 3000); */
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="card mb-3">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h2> Diseño Chat </h2>
          <form className="row mt-4" onSubmit={submitForm} >
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="inputDescription" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Título </h5>
              </label> 
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-11">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name='title'
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="inputDescription"
                required
              />
            </div>             
              
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="inputResponse" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Texto </h5>
              </label>              
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-11">
              <input
                type="textarea"
                className="form-control"
                name='text'
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="inputResponse"
                required
              />
            </div>              
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="link" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Link </h5>
              </label>
            </div>            
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="link"
                className="form-control"
                name="link"
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="link"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1">
              <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Title Link </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name='link_title'
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="link_title"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="image" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Image </h5>
              </label>
            </div>            
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="file"
                className="form-control"
                name="image"
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="image"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1">
              <label htmlFor="image_title" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Title Image </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name='image_title'
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="image_title"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-5" >
              <h3>DISEÑO VENTANA LATERAL</h3>
            </div>           
            <h5 className="ms-5 mb-5 mt-5"> Diseña  tu respuesta añadidendo subtitulos, texto, imagenes, documentos y enlaces. 
            Puedes seleccionarlos con el orden que mejor se ajuste a tu respuesta. Y puedes poner tantos elementos como quieras. </h5>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row align-item_lateral-center" >
                <div className="col-2 mt-3">
                  <h3>Título Ventana Lateral</h3>  
                </div>
                <div className="col-10">                 
                  <input
                    placeholder= 'Título Ventana Lateral'
                    className='form-control mt-3'
                    value={title_lateral}                    
                    onChange= {e=> setTitleLateral(e.target.value)}              
                    type="text"                         
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
               
              <div>
                {item_lateral.map((input, i) => ( 
                  <>  
                    { !(input.button_pressed === 'image' || input.button_pressed === 'links') && 
                   <div className="row align-item_lateral-center" key={input.button_pressed + i + 1}> 
                     <div className="col-2 mt-3">
                       <h3>{input.button_pressed}</h3>  
                     </div>
                     <div className="col-10">                 
                       <input
                         placeholder={input.button_pressed}
                         id={i}
                         className='form-control mt-3'                    
                         name={input.button_pressed}    
                         onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                         type="text"                         
                       />
                     </div>
                   </div>
                    }                               
                    {  input.button_pressed  === 'image' && 
                <>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key={input.button_pressed + i + 2}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Imagen: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-10'>
                      <input
                        placeholder='title_image_lateral'
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='title_image_lateral'   
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                             
                      /> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key={input.button_pressed + i + 1}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Image Path: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-10'>
                      <input
                        placeholder='path_image_lateral'
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='path_image_lateral'    
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                               
                      /> 
                    </div>
                  </div>                  
                </>
                    }                     
                    {input.button_pressed === 'links' &&
                <>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key={input.button_pressed + i+2}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Title Link: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8">
                      <input
                        placeholder='titel_link' 
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='titel_link'    
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                              
                      /> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row" key={i}>
                    <div className="col-2">
                      <h3>Link: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8">
                      <input
                        placeholder='link'
                        id={i}
                        className='form-control mt-3'                    
                        name='link'    
                        onChange= {e => handleChange(i, e)}              
                        type="text"                              
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
                    }  
                  </>                          
                ))}
            
              </div>             
              <div className="mt-5 text-center">               
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="text_item_lateral" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Text
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="title_item_lateral" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Subtitle
                </button>          
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="image" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Image
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="document_lateral" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add document
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="links" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Links
                </button> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div>
              {(isCreated && isVariationsSave) && 
              <div className="alert alert-success" role='alert'>
                      Respuesta CREADA Correctamente
              </div>
              }
              {isCreated && sendToCorpus()}
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-warning me-5 mb-3" type="submit" >Preview</button>
            <button className="btn btn-success me-5 mb-3" type="submit">Guardar Respuesta</button>
          </form>
          <div className="text-center">
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>  

    </>
  );
};

export default LateralWindow;
```

Comment: Please, paste the entire file.

Comment: Paulo you are my baywatch. :-)

Comment: Please notice that `let itemData = [...item_lateral];` only makes a copy of the array, not of the objects within it. Assigning to `itemData[i][e.target.name]` will still mutate the objects in your state - don't do that.

Comment: thanks but i don't understand the answer. i need to create this spread to go on mutating the object. itemData[i][e.target.name] this i use to know over the property i am working, or before read you, i did think that. could you explain somenthing more. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this suits your needs:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const LateralWindow = ({ token }) => {
  const itemDataObject = {
    sort: "",
    title_item_lateral: "",
    text_item_lateral: "",
    image_lateral: {
      title_image_lateral: "",
      path_image_lateral: "",
    },
    document_lateral: "",
    links: {
      title_link: "",
      link: "",
    },
  };

  const generalInfo = useSelector((state) => state.faqsGralInfo);
  const { description, typeResponse, rolViews, workLoadLevel, id, id_intent, corpusArea, corpusName } = generalInfo;

  const [finalResponse, setFinalResponse] = useState({});
  const [newJsonResponse, setNewJsonResponse] = useState({});
  const [title_lateral, setTitleLateral] = useState("");
  const [item_lateral, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [lateral, setNewLateral] = useState({
    title_lateral: title_lateral,
    item_lateral: [item_lateral],
  });

  let buttonPressed;

  const addFields = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonPressed = e.target.value;
    let newItemField;
    newItemField = { ...itemDataObject, button_pressed: buttonPressed };
    setItems([...item_lateral, newItemField]);
  };

  const handleChangeChat = (e) => {
    setFinalResponse({ ...finalResponse, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    setNewJsonResponse({
      ...newJsonResponse,
      accesToken: token,
      newDataResponse: {
        description,
        typeResponse,
        rolViews,
        workLoadLevel,
        id,
        id_intent,
        response_json_new: { finalResponse, lateral },
        corpusArea,
        corpusName,
        lateral_W: generalInfo.lateral_W === "true" ? 1 : 0,
      },
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (i, e) => {
    let itemData = [...item_lateral];
    let elementChanged = e.target;
    let name = elementChanged.name;
    let value = elementChanged.value;

    if (name === "title_image_lateral" || name === "path_image_lateral") {
      itemData[i].image_lateral[name] = value;
    } else if (name === "title_link" || name === "link") {
      itemData[i].links[name] = value;
    } else {
      itemData[i][name] = value;
    }

    setItems(itemData);
    setNewLateral({ ...lateral, item_lateral, title_lateral });
    handleChangeChat(e);
  };

  const submitForm = (e) => {
    console.log(item_lateral);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card mb-3">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h2> Diseño Chat </h2>
          <form className="row mt-4" onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="inputDescription" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Título </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-11">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" name="title" value="Titulo" onChange={handleChangeChat} id="inputDescription" required />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="inputResponse" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Texto </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-11">
              <input type="textarea" className="form-control" name="text" value="Texto" onChange={handleChangeChat} id="inputResponse" required />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="link" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Link </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input type="link" className="form-control" name="link" value="link" onChange={handleChangeChat} id="link" required />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1">
              <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Title Link </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" name="link_title" value="testeLink" onChange={handleChangeChat} id="link_title" required />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="image" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Image </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input type="file" className="form-control" name="image" onChange={handleChangeChat} id="image" required />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1">
              <label htmlFor="image_title" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Title Image </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="image_title"
                value="title image"
                onChange={handleChangeChat}
                id="image_title"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-5">
              <h3>DISEÑO VENTANA LATERAL</h3>
            </div>
            <h5 className="ms-5 mb-5 mt-5">
              Diseña tu respuesta añadidendo subtitulos, texto, imagenes, documentos y enlaces. Puedes seleccionarlos con el orden que mejor se ajuste
              a tu respuesta. Y puedes poner tantos elementos como quieras.{" "}
            </h5>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row align-item_lateral-center">
                <div className="col-2 mt-3">
                  <h3>Título Ventana Lateral</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="col-10">
                  <input
                    placeholder="Título Ventana Lateral"
                    className="form-control mt-3"
                    value={title_lateral}
                    onChange={(e) => setTitleLateral(e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="mt-5 text-center">
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="text_item_lateral" onClick={addFields}>
                  Add Text
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="title_item_lateral" onClick={addFields}>
                  Add Subtitle
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="image" onClick={addFields}>
                  Add Image
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="document_lateral" onClick={addFields}>
                  Add document
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="links" onClick={addFields}>
                  Add Links
                </button>
              </div>

              <div>
                {item_lateral.map((input, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={input.button_pressed + i}>
                      {!(input.button_pressed === "image" || input.button_pressed === "links") && (
                        <div className="row align-item_lateral-center">
                          <div className="col-2 mt-3">
                            <h3>{input.button_pressed}</h3>
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-10">
                            <input
                              placeholder={input.button_pressed}
                              id={i}
                              className="form-control mt-3"
                              name={input.button_pressed}
                              onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, e)}
                              type="text"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                      {input.button_pressed === "image" && (
                        <>
                          <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                              <h3>Imagen: </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-10">
                              <input
                                placeholder="title_image_lateral"
                                id={i}
                                className="form-control mt-3"
                                name="title_image_lateral"
                                onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, e)}
                                type="text"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                              <h3>Image Path: </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-10">
                              <input
                                placeholder="path_image_lateral"
                                id={i}
                                className="form-control mt-3"
                                name="path_image_lateral"
                                onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, e)}
                                type="text"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </>
                      )}
                      {input.button_pressed === "links" && (
                        <>
                          <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                              <h3>Title Link: </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-8">
                              <input
                                placeholder="title_link"
                                id={i}
                                className="form-control mt-3"
                                name="title_link"
                                onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, e)}
                                type="text"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="row align-item_lateral-center row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                              <h3>Link: </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-8">
                              <input
                                placeholder="link"
                                id={i}
                                className="form-control mt-3"
                                name="link"
                                onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, e)}
                                type="text"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
              {isCreated && isVariationsSave && (
            <div className="alert alert-success" role="alert">
              Respuesta CREADA Correctamente
            </div>
          )}
          {isCreated && sendToCorpus()}
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-warning me-5 mb-3" type="submit">
              Preview
            </button>
            <button className="btn btn-success me-5 mb-3" type="submit">
              Guardar Respuesta
            </button>
          </form>
          <div className="text-center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LateralWindow;
```

Comment: Yesterday night i achieve something like your response: 
 if(nameValue === 'image' ){
      itemData[i].image_lateral[0][e.target.name]=e.target.value;
    }else {
      itemData[i].links[0][e.target.name]=e.target.value;
    }
And works. i don't know why somone give you a -1 :-(. Thanks Paulo

Comment: It was because I made a joke in the answer, i talked about being a Babywatch hehe, i suppose we have to always be formal and serious here. If you don't mind could you Mark as accepted?